# Create public property of internal class?

Tags: c#

Suppose that I've this situation:

Base class or Mother class that declare this structure:

```
public static class Mother
{
     private static Childs _child = new Childs();

     public static Childs Child
     {
          get { return _child; }
     }
}
```

How you can see I want implement a singleton base class for access to all methods in one place as: Mother.Child.SomeMethod.

With this structure I've a better code organization.

Now I want make the Childs class only as internal, so here start the problem 'cause I can't create a public property of an internal class. The structure of internal class is the following:

```
internal class Childs
{
    public static bool SomeMethod() { ... }
}
```

so how can I make a public property of an internal class?

Comment: `public` only means "as public as possible". Since the class is `internal`, the method has the same maximum visibility: it's visible only within the same assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the child is internal, the static access point should be internal as well.

If you actually want to have public access to some members of the child, consider using an interface.

Anyway, if there is a static access point, you don't need to make members static.

```
public static class Mother
{
     private static Child _child = new Child();

     public static IChild Child
     {
          get { return _child; }
     }
}

public interface IChild
{
    // public stuff here
    bool SomeMethod();
}


internal class Child : IChild
{
    public bool SomeMethod() { ... }
    // additional internal members here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All classes in the inheritance tree must have at least the same visibility as the highest class in the hierarchy. There is no way to have a public class derive from an internal class.

Maybe your `Childs` class `public`. If you want to, you can make it `abstract` to prevent instantiating it or make the constructor internal to prevent deriving it in another assembly.

Comment: If I declare it as public abstract I can see it in antoher assembly anyway, maybe I understood wrong?

Comment: You can see it but you can't reuse it. There is no way to hide it from another assembly since the highest level class is `public`. All classes under that are required to be public too.

Comment: Umm, `abstract` won't stop them inheriting from it? For that you use `sealed`.

Comment: I didn't say `abstract` prevents deriving, did I? @juunas And sealing a base class isn't really helpful either.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sorry, misread your answer a bit :) Making the constructor internal indeed works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. If the property is public, any other class can access it. But if they are able to get it, they must also be able to access the class being received.